# operator does not exist: integer[] @@ integer[]

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have added an intarray column to my table and successfully added data to the column.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  ...
  tag_ids integer[],
)
```

When I try a query like this:

```
SELECT id, tag_ids from my_table where tag_ids @@ ARRAY[1,2]
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] @@ integer[]
LINE 1: SELECT id, tag_ids from core_tile where tag_ids @@ ARRAY[1,2...
                                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I installed 9.3 via Homebrew for OS X, which I believe includes the `intarray` module, and like I said I added the array column and data no problem. Also this:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions
...
"intarray";"1.0";"";"functions, operators, and index support for 1-D arrays of integers"
```

**Update:**

I wondered if I needed a specific index before the operators would work. In the example in [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/intarray.html) they add an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING GIST (tag_ids gist__int_ops);
```

But when I run that I get:

```
ERROR:  operator class "gist__int_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"
```

Am I missing an extension or is something wrong with the query or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the operators here such as `@>` all work:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html

It's just the additional ones here that didn't:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/intarray.html

That suggested to me the solution:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```

Running this against my db got all the operators working... I had assumed since Postgres was installed with `intarray` support it was all ready to go. But it has to be manually enabled for the db.

I guess this is so obvious for the Postgres devs they forgot to put it in the documentation.

Comment: There are a couple of related (possible helpful) [answers suggesting to create the extension `intarray`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgres]+create+extension+intarray+operator) for additional operators.

Comment: holy crap, thank you so much I was sitting here scratching my head why intarray stuff wouldn't work.